# fetch has no session in second call in React-Native on NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, express-session

First task my application does on startup is to make a `POST` call to the endpoint `/handshake` with an access token to authorize.

Node backend checks if the session variable `req.session.uid` is already set. Otherwise it'll check the access token from the `POST` body and sets the `req.session.uid` on valid access token.

It works properly when testing in Postman. Doing an API-Call after a successfull `/handshake` found place beforehand uses the `req.session.uid` within the request.

Unfortunately using fetch() in react-native shows an odd behavior, when session already existed before.

**Case (No Session Exists):**

1. `/handshake` with correct access token => backend sets `req.session.uid`
2. Every other call on the API works and uses the previously set uid.

**Case (Session Already Exist):**

3. `/handshake` with correct access token => backend sets no variable since `req.session.uid` is already set.
4. Making another API call => `req.session.id` is undefined

**I thought the issue may relate to issues in other api calls and tried to send another `/handshake` request when the first one succeeds:**

1. `/handshake` with correct access token => backend sets no variable since `req.session.uid`is already set.
2. `/handshake` with correct access token => backend sets `req.session.uid` since it is undefined

Every call after the second `/handshake` works properly. The main question here is, why does the backend recognizes me in the first `/handshake` call and does not when trying to make the second call?

Here is the code where `/handshake` request is called:

```js
       fetch(this.Links.handshake, 
            {body: myBody, method:"POST", credentials: "include",
            headers:{ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
       .then((response) => {
            if(response.ok)
                console.log("Handshake was successfull");
            else
                console.warn("Handshake failed ("+response.status+")!");
        }).catch(() => {
            console.warn("Error happened while handshake...");
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to the cookie being deleted after the first call.
I solved my issue by saving the cookie header by myself (saving the Set-Cookie header from the first request method and sending it with the 'cookie' header).